# In the present health crisis, do states plan to open their polling station for longer hours?

Tags: united-states, election, voting

I am always astonished at the shortness of the voting day in the US.

In Britain at general elections the polls are open across the whole country from 7.00am till 10.00pm. As a result they do not attract the lengthy queues that many US stations do, where people wait for hours to vote. And people can vote either on their way to or from the pub!

At a time of Covid infection it would seem to make sense to lengthen the voting day to allow for social distancing.

Is this happening?

Comment: In California, polls are open from 7:00 to 20:00, only two hours shorter. It can take several hours to finish processing the ballots, so closing at 22:00 would mean getting home midnight or later. Those extra two hours are well after rush hour. The main times for voting are right after the polls open, during lunch break, and right after people get off work. The only times I know of of significant wait times in California were during the recall election. I don't think wait times are a matter of not being open late enough, but of incompetence and/or deliberate vote suppression.

Comment: Closely related, though as of yet unanswered: [Why are there such long waits to vote in the US?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59392/19301)

Comment: @Acccumulation Would never work in Britain - think of the people who like to vote on their way home from the pub.

Comment: Why not?  Grocery stores have been open the entire time...

Comment: Elections in the US are administered by each state (of which there are fifty), and to some extent, by individual counties and municipalities (of which there are thousands). Your question might be easier to answer if you narrowed it down to a more specific location. As-is, the answer is almost certainly "It depends where you live," and I find it unlikely that someone is going to go through all fifty states in a comprehensive answer.